# Extracting latitude and longitude from HERE map linkid

Tags: python, here-api, here-maps-rest

Using HERE route matching API, I am finding out the linkid connecting the source and destination. Also, I am able to find out neighboring linkids to this linkid. Now I either want to plot the linkid onto the map.

How can I implement this in Python?

Comment: You [try to] implement it. If it doesn't work then come back with a specific question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.